# How to find an option in the database?

Tags: plugins, database, options, plugin-cforms

As far as I can tell, the plugin that I'm using is saving options to the wp_options file:

```
### New global settings container, will eventually be the only one!
$cformsSettings = get_option('cforms_settings');
```

When I go into phpmyadmin, however, I can't find the cforms_settings option_name?  Can anyone help me trouble-shoot this?  I have a backup of my old data but I can't add it.  I've also tried creating a completely new form and then searching the database and I've been unable to find it.  Very puzzled!!

Answer (score 0):

add_option()  and update_option() are the functions to save data in wp_options table.

Check in your plugin code whether this function saving 'cforms_settings' or not

Comment: It is using those functions:

` $cformsSettings['form'.$no]['cforms'.$no.'_tracking'] = '';
 $cformsSettings['form'.$no]['cforms'.$no.'_tellafriend'] = '01';
 $cformsSettings['form'.$no]['cforms'.$no.'_dashboard'] = '0';
 $cformsSettings['form'.$no]['cforms'.$no.'_maxentries'] = '';

    update_option('cforms_settings',$cformsSettings);`

Is it possible that myphpadmin is somehow hiding or obscuring this array?  It just doesn't show anything related to cforms_settings.